# TextArea and Multiline do not work in Unity 2022.1.0b10.2818

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

```
[TextArea] public string sds;
```

this code was supposed to make a string field expandable downwards but instead it directly hides it from the inspector. however the name of a string is still present. So it works at 50%. Strange.

[SCREENSHOT HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbjGz.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
[TextArea(10,10)]public string ss;
```

Second number confines the size of the area.
Secondly, if the text field is looking messed up then use it like this:

```
[NonReorderable]
[TextArea(10,10)]public string ss;
```

Comment: Tried it. Did not help :(

Comment: Which Unity version are you using?

Comment: 2022.1.0b10.2818, vanilla, no editor-changing extensions

Comment: If you don't have to use that exact version, just change it to something else.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same bug with this in unity 2022.2.0b7
Then Changed to minimum to 10 and it got resolved. It now shows atleast 10 minimum lines.

```
[SerializeField]
[TextArea(1, 12)]
public string Description;

[SerializeField]
[TextArea(10, 12)]
public string ChangeToDescription;
```